# Launch a frameless Chrome window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

From a command I would like to open a completely frameless Chrome window in Windows 7 or Windows 10.

Is there any combination of Chrome flags/features that will allow me to achieve this?

From what I recall, you can do this with a Chrome Packaged App, but this is now deprecated, so I'd like to avoid this.

E.g. `chrome --app=Http://www.google.co.uk` will open a Chrome window with a frame and titlebar only - but I am looking for no frame at all.

Answer (score 0):

> google-chrome --kiosk "http://www.google.com"

will open chrome without frame in linux.

flag : --kiosk

Comment: This is not a window though, this is fullscreen.

Comment: You can use electron.js to open a chrome page in window

Comment: I am looking to achieve this with a vanilla `Google Chrome` install.

Comment: What is the purpose of this ? If you want a standalone application then [electron.js](https://electronjs.org/) is a good option.

Comment: electron.js does nothing but opens a web application in one tab of google chrome.